# How to predict CMake's choice of LIBDIR on a given platform

Tags: cmake, libtiff, pengwin, pengwin-enterprise

In my application suite I build Libtiff from source and then link it to an application that I write myself. Libtiff's CMakeLists.txt files specify that the static libraries go into the library location CMAKE_INSTALL_FULL_LIBDIR, determined by CMake's GNUInstallDirs option.

When I first built and tested my application, I did so in Debian and on this platform CMAKE_INSTALL_FULL_LIBDIR gets set to ${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}/lib. Well and good, so in my own application's CMakeLists.txt file I told it to search for the the static tiff libraries there. No problem...

Now I've taken the same build suite to a Red Hat Linux platform (Pengwin Enterprise for WSL), and it turns out that here CMAKE_INSTALL_FULL_LIBDIR gets set to ${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}/lib**64**. I've checked [the CMake documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/GNUInstallDirs.html) and it seems to say that in fact the choice of 'lib' or 'lib64' is determined automatically and is platform-dependent.

So, in my own application's CMakeLists.txt file, is there a way of finding out which it is on my current platform? How else am I supposed to guess where to look for the library? I've looked round but I can't find a CMAKE standard variable that holds the platform-dependent string, so the only things I can think of are:

1. Try 'lib', and if that doesn't work try 'lib64', or
2. Create a new CMAKE_INSTALL_FULL_LIBDIR in my own CMakeLists.txt file and read the end of it

...but both these seem clunkily inelegant and there surely must be a better way.

Comment: "Try 'lib', and if that doesn't work try 'lib64', or" - I have seen several projects which use given approach.

Comment: highly related question here: [How does CMake decide to make a lib or lib64 directory for installations?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76517286/11107541)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[GNUInstallDirs](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.14/module/GNUInstallDirs.html) module documents the CMAKE_INSTALL_LIBDIR variable which sounds like it contains the value you want.

```
CMAKE_INSTALL_LIBDIR = lib
CMAKE_INSTALL_FULL_LIBDIR = /lib
```

Also `find_library` should also be searching `lib` and `lib64` as necessary in the default path search even when using `CMAKE_LIBRARY_PATH` to define a custom prefix.

Comment: Yes, that's it. As is usually my experience when reading the CMake documentation, it's not at all clear when reading it in isolation; but having been given that hint and looked up a few usage examples on the internet, it's obvious that that's the solution.